# Can't get sign in credential

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase Authentication sample.
I have code that does Google sign in with Firebase.

```
private void handleSignInResult(Intent data) {
    try {
        // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
        SignInCredential credential = signInClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data);
        String idToken = credential.getGoogleIdToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + credential.getId());
        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
        Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
        updateUI(null);
    }
}
```

Got exception on `signInClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data)`

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: Account authorization failed
at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbbg.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@20.7.0:6)
at com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth.java.GoogleSignInFragment.handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInFragment.java:127)
at com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth.java.GoogleSignInFragment.-$$Nest$mhandleSignInResult(Unknown Source:0)
at com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth.java.GoogleSignInFragment$1.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInFragment.java:72)
at com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth.java.GoogleSignInFragment$1.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInFragment.java:69)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:414)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:371)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:845)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:151)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8310)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5008)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5056)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Why I'm getting this exception and how to solve it?

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).